# iOS - Rotate image while moving it

Tags: ios, image, animation, rotation

i use an `NSTimer` to move an `UIImageView`, insted of `UIView` animation for several reasons. I have also to rotate it while it's moving. Is it possible? Some sample code?
Thanks

Comment: You should provide some more context, and what you've tried.

Comment: And look over here for rotation a UIImageView : http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2012/05/24/how-to-rotate-a-uiimageview-roulette-tutorial/

Comment: @rdurand the code u have linked is good, but when i use it it seems my image is being extended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I move my `UIImageView` I change its frame changing its `y` value. So, it's impossible to transform an object while its frame is changing. So, to move my `UIImageView` I now change its `center` property and the transform works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Apply a transformation to the view

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; //if not set in xib it must be set here
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(move:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)move:(id)timer {
    CGRect f = self.imageView.frame;
    static CGFloat angle = 1;

    f.origin.x += 5;
    f.origin.y += 10;
    self.imageView.frame = f;

    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle); //!!!
    angle += 10;
}
```

Comment: When I use this code it seems that my image is being extended, i don't know why.